# GRASS 7 raster map calculator

Tags: grass-gis, raster-calculator, ndvi

I am new to GRASS and am trying to use it because I can't afford the Spatial Analyst extension in ArcGIS.

I am trying to remove all of the values in a NDVI raster less than some value to exclude shadows and bare soil before I calculate averages.  I have tried

NDVI_b = if(NDVI_a <= 0.1,null(),NDVI_a)

My understanding is that this statement means that a new map (NDVI_b) should be created where cell values <= 0.1 are replaced with null otherwise the value remains the same as in NDVI_a.  However all I'm getting is null value for all cells in my output raster.  Is there something fundamental that I'm missing?  I have tried using both the GUI Raster Map Calculator as well as the command console.

Comment: Have you set your region to match the NDVI_a raster? (This is FAQ #0 for GRASS users. **Always** set the region first)

Comment: Yes, I did set my region to match my raster and I opened it and it projected correctly.  I think that it is a problem with my Geotiff.  I was able to do something similar with a sample raster that I downloaded, but I can't get it to work with a geotiff that was outputted by Pix4D.  I compared the gdalinfo for my file and the downloaded file but did not notice substantial differences.  I thought that a geotiff was a goetiff.

Comment: When I run r.mapcalc on my geotiff, the output raster is basically empty:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out - the problem was that my original geotiff was not properly projected.  I fixed the projection and the raster calculation works.